# how to specify java runtime range with build granularity in jnlp

Tags: java, jnlp

Because of a [serious bug in Java 8 Update 40](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8075029) which was fixed in Java 8 Update 40 build 27, I would like to specify that build as minimum in my JNLP. However this does not seem to work:

```
<resources>
  <java version="1.8.0_40-b27+"/>
```

Strangely, it doesn't work even if I specify exactly the build, which is currently installed on my machine, Java Web Start tells the me it's not, in my case I did:

```
<resources>
  <java version="1.8.0_40-b27"/>
```

Is it possible to somehow specify the Java runtime version in this granularity, after all?

**Update:** At least I can specify a range with update granularity (but not build granularity), if a certain href is provided:

```
<resources>
  <java version="1.8.0_40+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
```

Comment: Good luck getting anything but the most up to date installed JRE.  Oracle seems to have (quietly) dropped support for loading & using earlier JREs.